# View is not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my application the main view is loaded with a _Layout.vbhtml master page. I render a few sections and the default `contractNumber` is printed out correctly. When I change the Model's `contractNumber` the view does not reflect the change and shows the default value. 
Here is the code from the section in my `Index.vbhtml` file that calls the Model:

```
 @Section  CUInfo 
Contract Number: @Model.contractNumber

 End Section
```

In my _Layout.vbhtml page I have:

```
@RenderSection("CUInfo", required:=True)
```

I know that the `contractNumber` has the correct value in it, when I step through the code, it passes over the `@Model.contractNumber` line.

Comment: What is this? Why are you using `HttpContext.Current.Session`? From what I can see nothing is passed to your view. It is the view that is trying to fetch some information from sessions and stuff which is absolutely not something that a view should be doing. It is unclear what your question/problem is. It is unclear what is the `sessionValues` method that you are calling. It is unclear how/where your application stores anything into this Session. Your question hardly makes any sense. If you don't update it to make it more clear I am afraid it will get closed.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I updated the question. I hope it makes more sense now, please let me know if you have any other questions. I was using the session stuff because in my application depending on which session the user is in, the app will show a different `contractNumber`. I took that out to make it easier to read/understand (I hope).

Comment: You talk about some changing of the value of the `contractNumber` property. Where does this changing of value occur? Also you have removed the session to make your question clear, but did you also remove it in your code and proven that the problem still persists?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I am using MEF with my MVC3 app. In one of my plug-ins is where I call the `contractNumber` property on an imported HostApp object. Then I return the Index view of my host app while also passing the HostApp object. I would be returning the same thing with or without the session code, and the session code is built into my app. My question is about why the view won't "rerender" (sorry for lack of a better word). I know the values in my Model are correct.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand anything from your question. Maybe its due to the lacking example allowing to reproduce the issue. Good luck in finding the cause of the problem.